# Luis get intent API is not sending me right intent?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am using [Cognitive Service's LUIS API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c08) to get intent of any particular text like I want to get the intent of "I want to talk with agent". So here I should get "agent" intent which I am getting from Luis UI Test window but with the same text when I tried to get through API's I am getting the different intent.

Luis UI Test window :

[image]

But this is the response I am getting from API call :

```
  {
    "query": "i want to talk with agent",
      "topScoringIntent": {
      "intent": "Help",
        "score": 0.212456271
    },
    "intents": [
      {
        "intent": "Help",
        "score": 0.212456271
      },
      {
        "intent": "Cancel",
        "score": 0.07567735
      },
      {
        "intent": "None",
        "score": 0.0337549262
      },
      {
        "intent": "Greeting",
        "score": 0.02286759
      }
    ],
      "entities": [],
        "sentimentAnalysis": {
      "label": "negative",
        "score": 0.09926739
    }
  }
```

Comment: Okay..Its working now after publish :) But do we have any API to publish my app?

Comment: Publish API https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c3b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you haven't published it yet, make sure to publish it through the portal or use the [API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c3b) to do so.